# Cannot make permanent changes with sed

Tags: linux, sed, scripting

I want that command to be permanent :

```
sudo sed -E "s/( )[^#]*/\1$(cat tmp_script) /" hosts
```

So i tried with -i instead but it's not working. It tells me to change the part with \1
but when i do it nothing happends on hosts file anymore.

I just want the first command to be able to write on the file.

Comment: Have you tried using both `-i` and `-E`? Those aren't mutually exclusive you know

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `awk`?

Comment: @Paolo Yes already tried.